# error Type sp.TInt / sp.TNat mismatch

Tags: smartpy, error, types

```
Error: Type sp.TInt / sp.TNat mismatch
sp.is_nat expects a sp.TInt
Got: sp.TNat
line 119
```

Line: 119

```
self.data.shop_items[item_to_purchase.key].amount -= sp.as_nat(item_to_purchase.value)
```

I'm not sure where the `sp.TInt` is coming from... All the numbers are supposed to be `sp.TNat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing math on nats casts them to an int. The value needs to be casted back to a nat after the subtraction:

```
self.data.shop_items[item_to_purchase.key].amount = sp.as_nat(self.data.shop_items[item_to_purchase.key].amount - item_to_purchase.value)
```

Comment: Not all math. Only when they involve a difference (of the unitary minus operator). Otherwise, your answer is good!